# Postgres Capturing History With Truncate

Tags: postgresql

Running Postgres 9.6 on AWS Aurora

I have a table where I am capturing history.  I use triggers to change UPDATEs and DELETEs into INSERTs and added an operation column with a date to log the changes.

The problem is some ETL code which I do not control TRUNCATES and repopulates the table.  What I want is a mechanism to override the TRUNCATE and 'soft' truncate any active rows.  Postgres only supports INSTEAD OF triggers on views and you cannot have a TRUNCATE trigger on a view.  So net - no INSTEAD OF TRUNCATE trigger.

What I have done:
BEFORE TRUNCATE trigger to move all the data in the table to a new table
Let the truncate truncate run
AFTER TRUNCATE trigger to move all the data back and insert the new soft truncate rows.

I would prefer a solution where I do not have to move so much data.

I don't own the ETL code and getting the ETL developers to change their code would involve standing up a new project, testing...

Comment: if you just want history, then you need to insert all truncated rows (which is much data anyway) or save a statement (meant for truncate). so if you choose first option - you already did it (not sure why you copy there-back though)...

Comment: Let say I am capturing history for years.  I have millions of rows in the history, but only 1000 active.   I want to copy just those 1000 rows with an operation of  TRUNCATE and append that to my table.   As far as copying all the data back - I want all the data in the original table.